# Using quarterly data on daily data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I'm trying to do some feature engineering with daily stock prices and their financial statements.

Say if the stock_price table columns look like this, with rows updating every day.

```
OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOL | DATE
1    | 3    | 0.8 | 1.2   | 5   | 2020-10-1
1.2  | 1.3  | 1   | 1.28  | 3   | 2020-10-2
1.4  | 2.1  | 1.4 | 2.0   | 5   | 2020-10-3
...
0.9  | 1.3  | 0.7 | 1     | 3   | 2021-1-8
1.2  | 1.5  | 1   | 1.4   | 3   | 2021-1-9
```

The financial_statements table columns look like this

```
REVENUE | EPS | PUBLISHED_DATE
0.8     | 0.8 | 2020-7-1           < Q2 data
1       | 1   | 2020-10-2          < Q3 data
1.6     | 1.6 | 2021-1-9           < Q4 data
```

Then I want to get this

```
OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOL | DATE       | REVENUE_X_10
1    | 3    | 0.8 | 1.2   | 5   | 2020-10-1  | 8
1.2  | 1.3  | 1   | 1.28  | 3   | 2020-10-2  | 10        < Q3 statement published this day
1.4  | 2.1  | 1.4 | 2.0   | 5   | 2020-10-3  | 10
...                                                      < all these rows use Q3 data
0.9  | 1.3  | 0.7 | 1     | 3   | 2021-1-8   | 10        
1.2  | 1.5  | 1   | 1.4   | 3   | 2021-1-9   | 16        < Q4 statement published this day
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Show us some sample data, expected output and database that you are using. Not everyone is aware about the term P/E ratio. So make the logic clear in your question. I am voting to close this question. If you will update the question with required details then I will retract my vote and will try to answer your question.

Comment: Just edited the question. Thanks for the advice. I don't have the data yet. Just made up some. Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
select sp.*,
       (select fs.revenue * 10
        from financial_statements fs
        where fs.published_date <= sp.date
        order by fs.publichsed_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as fs_revenue_times_10
from stock_price sp
```

Comment: @MonSh1rE . . . I have no idea why you would get that error when `in`, `all`, and `any` aren't used in this query.

Comment: I was talking about another query but nvm. This one I get "EXPECTING EOF" when I just paste it in with the query. Is it the LIMIT keyword? I'm using mysql btw.

Comment: @MonSh1rE . . . The code is syntactically correct:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d78cac0dbc44bf6afe6aac9ab4a0ece.  It works.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tommorrow. I'm noob to mysql maybe I've done it wrong first.